# Script cannot find/call function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have some code in a folder which contains some basic functions regarding fuzzy sets. These folders are `@fset` and `@mftrap`. I can call the functions from those folders without any problem.

Now I defined a new function, `tsmodel.m`. I putted this first in the root i.e.

```
/root
 + /@fset
 + /@mftrap
 - tsmodel.m
 - example.m
```

I could call `tsmodel.m` from `example.m`. Now I putted it in `@fset` folder since it is related. But now my `example.m` file cannot find `tsmodel.m` anymore for some reason while I can still call all other functions located in `@fset` folder. I get the following error:

```
Undefined function 'tsmodel' for input arguments of type
'cell'.

Error in example (line 21)
Y = tsmodel(X,t,a,b);
```

I believe the problem lies in the fact that the folder `@fset` is declared as a class or something.

Hopefully anyone can tell me what is going wrong.

-edit-

Sorry I forgot to include the files:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20782274/fuzzy.zip

-edit2-

I now changed the @fset folder to a single class file. How can I now set method of `tsmodel` such that it can accept a cell array of fset methods?

```
    classdef fset
    properties (SetAccess = private)
        mu
        x
    end

    methods  
        function A = fset(x,m)
        % constructor for a fuzzy set
            if nargin < 2 
                m = ones(size(x)); 
            end

            if isa(m,'fset') 
                A = m; 
                return; 
            end

            if isa(m,'mftrap'), 
               A.mu = mu(x,m); 
            else 
               A.mu = m(:); 
            end

            A.x = x(:);
        end

        function h = plot(A,linetype)
        % plot membership function
            if nargin < 2
                linetype = 'b'; 
            end

            A = A(:);

            hs = ishold;

            for i = 1 : length(A)
               handle(i) = plot(A(i).x,A(i).mu,linetype);
               hold on
            end

            if ~hs
                hold off;
            end

            title(inputname(1))
            ylabel('mu');
            xlabel('x');

            if nargout
                h = handle;
            end
        end

        function display(A)
        % display fuzzy set as a pointwise list
            A  = A(:);
            lA = length(A);

            for i = 1:lA
                if iscell(A(i).x)
                    if lA > 1
                        str = sprintf('%s(%d) = \n\n  %s', ...
                                      inputname(1),i,'fuzzy relation');
                    else   
                        str = sprintf('%s = \n\n  %s', ...
                                      inputname(1),'fuzzy relation');
                    end;

                    disp(str);
                    disp(A(i).mu);
                else   
                    list = [A(i).mu'; A(i).x'];
                    list = list(:);

                    if size(list,1) < 10,
                        s = sprintf('%1.2f/%1.2f, ',list);
                    else
                        list1 = list(1:4,:);
                        list2 = list(end-3:end,:);
                        s = [sprintf('%1.2f/%1.2f, ',list1(:)) '..., ' ...
                             sprintf('%1.2f/%1.2f, ',list2(:))];
                    end;

                    if lA > 1,
                        str = sprintf('%s(%d) = \n\n  fuzzy set\n  { %s }', ...
                                      inputname(1),i,s(1:end-2));
                    else   
                        str = sprintf('%s = \n\n  fuzzy set\n  { %s }', ...
                                      inputname(1),s(1:end-2));
                    end;

                    disp(str);

                end
            end
        end

        function Y = tsmodel(A,X,a,b)
        % TSMODEL
        % input:
        %   X, dataset
        %   A, fuzzy set
        %   a, affine linear function parameter
        %   b, affine linear function parameter
        % output:
        %   Y, output

            % check input
            if isempty(X) || isempty(A) || ...
               isempty(a) || isempty(b)
                error('Not all necesary parameters are given.');
                return;
            end

            % check if singleton model (only b are given)
            if size(a) == 0
                a = zeros(1,length(b));
            end

            % check dimension A and a and trap and b
            if length(A) ~= length(a) || length(A) ~= length(b)
                error('Dimensions do not match');
                return;
            end

            % init storage variables
            Y      = zeros(length(X),1);
            weight = zeros(length(A),1);

            % for each x in X
            for k = 1:length(X)

                % for each rule
                for i = 1:length(A)
                    weight(i) = mu(X(k),A{i});
                end

                % compute weighted mean
                Y(k) = sum(weight .* (a*X(k) + b)) / sum(weight);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File in the `@fset` folder are all "methods" of the class `fset`. That means, they should all "operate on" `fset` objects. In fact, they all take an `fset` as their first parameter.

- If your method is like that, i.e. it acts upon `fset` objects, then it does belong in the `@fset` folder. In this case, you need to edit the file `/@fset/fset.m` which defines the class, and add it to the `methods` section. It should then become visible.
- If your method isn't like that, i.e. it *doesn't* operate on an `fset` object, then it doesn't strictly belong in the `@fset` folder -- even though it's related. That's just the law! you can put it anywhere else.

see [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/organizing-classes-in-folders.html) for how to organise the class folders, and 
[here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/ordinary-methods.html#brdqipw-1) for how to edit the class definition file.

Comment: I changed the `@fset` folder to a single class file, see my update. However how can I make it such that the tsmodel can accept a cell array of fset objects?

Comment: That is a good question, and I think this is one place where matlab falls down. It's not a true object-oriented language, and AFAIK doesn't have a collection framework that allows you to do such things easily. One solution is that, if you are simply iterating the existing method over the cell items, to use the built in `cellfun` etc which will nicely parallelise things. If you're doing something more complex, I have a feeling you'll need to have the cell-version of the function separately.